# Join PDFs calling join.py OSX script from another python script and passing parameters

Tags: python, macos, pdf

Please keep in mind i am very new to python.

I have been trying to write a python script that among other things, uses the join.py Python script already present in OSX (see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/99218) to merge pdf files from a specific folder.

The way this script is supposed to work is by providing the following arguments:
`join.py -o OutputDir/Outputfilename InputDir/*.pdf` when in shell.
This will take all the pdfs of the input filenames and merge them. I have successfully done this with a shell script but trying to run it with python i have not managed to make it grab all the pdfs, with any way i've tried. It always refuses to process a list of files, just wants a string.

My latest script:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/System/Library/Automator/Combine PDF Pages.action/Contents/Resources/')
pdfInputDir = os.path.join (sortsdir, expTitle, "PDFs")
print(pdfInputDir)
pdfstomerge = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(pdfInputDir):
    pdfstomerge += glob.glob(os.path.join(root, '*.pdf'))
print(pdfstomerge) #i verify the pdfs are the ones i want
from subprocess import call
call(["/System/Library/Automator/Combine PDF Pages.action/Contents/Resources/join.py", "-o", os.path.join(pdfInputDir, "output.pdf"), ''.join(map(str, pdfstomerge))])
###
###
```

Every time i run it i get an output.pdf correctly produced which is empty. To verify that what i am doing is working, i have switched *.pdf with one of the pdf filenames i have in the directory and it has produced an output.pdf with that file, meaning i am on the right track, i just can't figure out a way to provide it with all the necessary pdfs instead of one.

I am not sure what i am doing wrong anymore, especially since the above "command" works in terminal. I've tried different approaches including `os.path.join(pdfInputDir, "*.pdf")` , re'match and fnmatch but none of them worked - i usually get an error along these lines:
`TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly`
 (could be i wrote them wrong).

Also, i am pretty sure that i could perhaps run it as a python module, instead of calling it with subprocess but then i failed to find a way to "push" all the required arguments in it, so i stuck with the subprocess.call way.

Any ideas on how to properly provide those parameters for my script would be more than appreciated.

Comment: Hi Steve, if the command works on a shell, why are you not using the os.system("command") call instead of subprocess. Just give it a try. Since in your code I cannot see any access to the subprocess created, than an os.system can maybe work.

Comment: Last but not least pdfstomerge is established as a list, but can it be that the glob.glob() is giving you only one line full of files instead of a list (not sure since I have not tried that!). BTW you are on the good track!!

Comment: @Marcosmdm Hey and thanks for your replies! If i was getting a line full of files, instead of a list, wouldn't it make sense that the error would not claim it cannot convert a list to a string? Also, when i print(pdfstomerge) i see the following : ['pdf1', 'pdf2', 'pdf3'....]. I am going to give a try to your os.system suggestion and come back.

Comment: os.system("command") call is giving me again the same error: `TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly`

Comment: This I guess it is how the cmd line is parsing those values....Then why don't you create out of the list a string?.... from pdfstomerge.....you can easily strpdfmerge = "[" + ",".join(str(i) for i in pdfstomerge) + "]"  Please give it a try :-) I think the problem is just that :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try join(str(i) for i in pdfstomerge) instead of join(map(str, pdfstomerge).

This should solve your query :-) (hopefully) Have a nice day!

```
try:
   liststr = ','join(str(i) for i in pdfstomerge)
   print(liststr)
except TypeError:
   print(pdfstomerge) # to check what you have in the list of pdfs
```

In addition I am not sure if you have to pass the value in a string like:

```
stringToCall = '[' + liststr + ']'
```

## Hope you will find soon a solution.

Comment: Tried both your suggestions but unfortunately to no avail :/ I have replaced the join(map(str, pdfstomerge) with join(str(i) for i in pdfstomerge), tried to run it with both os.system or subprocess.call. Then i also created strpdfmerge and tried again with both "commands". I still get either an empty file or the aforementioned list error. Small note: every time i run it with subprocess.call it creates an empty output file, while every time i run it with os.system it gives me the list to string error (don't know if this indicates something importnat)

Comment: Have you tried away of  the call or os.system call? Try to build that part before, you can also add a try as I add to my answer

Comment: Hey Marco and thanks again for your help. Indeed i tried them both. When i do the `try` it doesn't print (pdfstomerge), which i am guessing means i still get the TypeError.

Comment: That should be indeed good...Just try to print the liststr than...If something is going wrong in the execution after the try and there is a TypeError then the print should come. But in case of no error, there is not a print :-) Hope this help you.

Comment: Something can help you is to build completely the command you are running and print it as a string, before to send it to os.system or call. This will tell you at least if you are calling the correct command or building it wrongly. Last but not least it has to work, since you have tried on the cli :-)

Comment: So indeed i got it to work with your final suggestion. I build the whole line up as a string
    
    
        `stringToCall = "%s %s %s%s" % ("./join.py -o", EndPdf, pdfInputDir,"/*.pdf")
       os.system(stringToCall)
        #`

And it now works perfectly. What "irritates" me is that i am absolutely sure it could have been done with the `subprocess.call` way (which looked more elegant) i just couldn't figure it out.
If anyone ever has an idea about this, please let me know, otherwise i guess its solved.

Thanks again for your help Marco!

Comment: I was expecting so :-) Congratulations and keep up the good work!! Please close the question if it's ok for you! Ciao ciao and have a nice day!

Comment: subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=100)

Comment: you can have a look at the popen coming from subprocess...then for instance you can even sniff the output and work with that real time :-) I am usually doing that, but when you run commands where you don't want to check anything (or don't have to control), than I would stick to easy os.system(command) ;)